# #include <CGAL/IO/reader_helpers.h> causes error C2039: 'Point_3': is not a member of 'CGAL'

Tags: c++, windows, cgal

I am currently running into the issue that if I include (not using it anywhere in the code yet) <CGAL/IO/reader_helpers.h> in my program I get some build errors:

```
1>C:\dev\CGAL-5.0.2\include\CGAL/IO/reader_helpers.h(61,71): error C2039: 'Point_3': is not a member of 'CGAL'
1>C:\dev\CGAL-5.0.2\include\CGAL/IO/reader_helpers.h(21): message : see declaration of 'CGAL'
1>C:\dev\CGAL-5.0.2\include\CGAL/IO/reader_helpers.h(61,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Point_3'
```

I actually want to include <CGAL/IO/STL_reader.h>, but that includes <CGAL/IO/reader_helpers.h>.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: You probably also need to include a kernel somewhere, did you try including the kernel **before** this file? You could also use a more recent of CGAL where this file includes CGAL/Point_3.h.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few changes in the IO packages; that header got renamed, I'm amid trying to things running with the new version (5.2.1)

```
https://www.cgal.org/2021/03/17/cgal521/
```

see :

```
commit 37b5928df2b4e80c09cf2cb94361827221a649a1
Author: Maxime Gimeno <maxime.gimeno@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 1 11:33:35 2020 +0100

    Fixes of warnings and errors

diff --git a/Stream_support/include/CGAL/IO/helpers.h b/Stream_support/include/CGAL/IO/helpers.h
index f261337bac..ead5a86c45 100644
--- a/Stream_support/include/CGAL/IO/helpers.h
+++ b/Stream_support/include/CGAL/IO/helpers.h
@@ -30,7 +30,8 @@ namespace internal {
 template <typename Kernel>
 void fill_point(const double x, const double y, const double z, const double w, CGAL::Point_3<Kernel>& pt)
 {
-  pt = CGAL::Point_3<Kernel>(x, y, z, w);
+  typedef typename Kernel::FT FT;
+  pt = CGAL::Point_3<Kernel>(FT(x/w), FT(y/w), FT(z/w));
 }
 
 template <typename Point_3>
```